# URL blocked by CORS policy No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in magento2

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.4.2, permissions, cors

i am using google translate for my custom module.i am facing issue on console as per given image for reference i have given code of phtml file.

console error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aBuC.png

> vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\test.phtml

```
<div id="google_translate_element" style="float: left;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit()
    {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {
            pageLanguage: '<?php echo $bashlanguage; ?>',
            includedLanguages: '<?php echo $lanselected; ?>',
            <?php echo $layouthtml; ?>
        },
        'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

> I am follwing this solution but isn't working. magento_root :- .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|json)$">
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Host, Content-Type, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"
```